# Data provider is not running in Selenium Grid

Tags: testng, selenium-grid, jxl

Can anyone please tell me that why the below error occurs: it occurs for all data provider methods. I use a static class for entire data providers and am using @Test(dataProvider = "Search", dataProviderClass= StaticProvider.class). it was running when i run normally with a test but on running Selenium Grid with 2 test all my data providers are throwing the below exception. I am running in sequential mode as i could not succed in parallel run.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: jxl.read.biff.BiffException: Compound file does not contain the specified stream

org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeDataProvider(MethodInvocationHelper.java:130)
org.testng.internal.Parameters.handleParameters(Parameters.java:413)
org.testng.internal.Invoker.handleParameters(Invoker.java:1319)
org.testng.internal.Invoker.createParameters(Invoker.java:1021)
org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1121)
org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
org.testng.TestRunner.runWorkers(TestRunner.java:1182)
org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:761)
org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:612)
org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:335)
org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:330)
org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:292)
org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:241)
org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1169)
org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1094)
org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1006)
org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:107)
org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:199)
org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:170)
Caused by: jxl.read.biff.BiffException: Compound file does not contain the specified stream

jxl.read.biff.CompoundFile.getPropertyStorage(CompoundFile.java:451)
jxl.read.biff.CompoundFile.getStream(CompoundFile.java:326)
jxl.read.biff.File.<init>(File.java:135)
jxl.Workbook.getWorkbook(Workbook.java:221)
jxl.Workbook.getWorkbook(Workbook.java:198)
com.lm.sl.StaticProvider.getTableArray(StaticProvider.java:135)
com.lm.sl.StaticProvider.createSearch(StaticProvider.java:32)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:80)
org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeDataProvider(MethodInvocationHelper.java:117)
org.testng.internal.Parameters.handleParameters(Parameters.java:413)
org.testng.internal.Invoker.handleParameters(Invoker.java:1319)
org.testng.internal.Invoker.createParameters(Invoker.java:1021)
org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1121)
org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
org.testng.TestRunner.runWorkers(TestRunner.java:1182)
org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:761)
org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:612)
org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:335)
org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:330)
org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:292)
org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:241)
org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1169)
org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1094)
org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1006)
org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:107)
org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:199)
org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:170)
```

Comment: Found that the excel sheet got corrupted.. with new excel it works fine

Comment: Can you add this as answer and close?

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs because the excel got corrupted.